# Rmarkdown is throwing some error when knit

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

Trust that you're doing great.

Please I came across an error anytime I knit in markdown

Please see the error below.

`Error in xfun::normalize_path(path, ..., must_work = must_work, resolve_symlink = FALSE) :  unused argument (resolve_symlink = FALSE) Calls: <Anonymous> -> normalize_path Execution halted`

The thing is that it has been working for a very long time before
I have uninstalled and reinstalled both the R and rstudio still the same thing.

The error started the moment some packages began giving me some update issue which has been updated and all packages are working fine now, only for me to knitt to markdown then the error appeared

Comment: I ran into this problem last week and solved it by updating `xfun` to the latest development version from GitHub: `install.packages('xfun', repos = 'https://yihui.r-universe.dev')`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment 
Do you wanna provide this as your answer so that I can tick it for you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem last week and solved it by updating xfun to the latest development version from GitHub: `install.packages('xfun', repos = 'https://yihui.r-universe.dev')`.

I'm happy to hear it worked for you too.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem downgrading to R v 3.6. In my case, I closed all markdowns, then in a clean session, the first thing I do is reinstall tinytext and xfun (compilation required).

`install.packages("tinytext")`

`install.packages("xfun")`

After restarting, the problem is solved.